# Adding an action to happen at Login

Tags: php, login

I am not new to expression engine but the question i have returns no answers in google.

I need to:

@ the time of successful login
 - do something outside of expression engine (various external requirements)

Ideally i would like to add an include/function(php/sql) at the right place to run at the time of successful login each new login.

I could achieve this by `if {logged_in}`.

But this is not really the solution i had hoped for.

Is there a place where i can add to the login-complete part of expression engine?

If so, where is it / is there documentation for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the session_start hook.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/session/index.html#id2